# How to get local "rotation" of a face

Tags: python

Using the `scene.ray_cast` method I'm able to get the information of a polygon that the mouse runs over in the 3DVIEW.

```
def cast_ray(context, event):
    # cast ray from mouse location, return data from ray
    # start_time = time.time()
    scene = context.scene
    region = context.region
    rv3d = context.region_data
    coord = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y
    viewlayer = context.view_layer
    if bpy.app.version >= (2, 91, 0):  # well actually under 2.93 but it works
        viewlayer = viewlayer.depsgraph
    # get the ray from the viewport and mouse
    view_vector = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, rv3d, coord)
    ray_origin = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_origin_3d(region, rv3d, coord)

    hit, location, normal, index, object, matrix = scene.ray_cast(viewlayer, ray_origin, view_vector)
    #       hit : bool - if ray found a face
    #  location : position on face ray hit in global space
    #    normal : normal of face ray hit
    #     index : index number of face in object ray hit
    #    object : object ray hit
    #    matrix : ??

    if hit:
        # get data of face ray hit from it's index number
        poly = object.data.polygons[index]

        # get world vector of face normal
        face_location, face_rotation, face_scale = matrix.decompose()

        # this returns Z axis orientated to face normal
        # ??? need X,Y axis orientated to face somehow ???
        face_direction = face_rotation @ poly.normal
        face_matrix = Matrix.LocRotScale(face_location, face_direction.to_track_quat("Z", "Y"), face_scale)

        return hit, location, normal, index, object, face_matrix
    else:
        return hit, location, normal, index, object, matrix
```

However I'd like to return the "local rotation" of the face that the ray hits but with it's Z axis pointing along it's normal. (not even sure "rotation" is the correct term) I can get the Z axis aligned correctly, but I have no idea how to align the other 2 axis, or what the rotation portion of the returned matrix even refers to. My assumption was that the `matrix` returned from `ray_cast` would be aligned to the face, but it does not seem to be and the documentation on this is lacking.

In other words, I can get the Z axis to align with the face normal, but I'd also like the X,Y axis to align with the face, like the Move Widget does when clicking a face in `EDIT MODE` with `Transform Orientation` set to `Normal`
Note how X,Y axis markers are pointing "square" to the face, not world or object.
[image]

My code above gives the rotation looking like this for the same face in the previous image:
(Although, all the objects have been combined into one object when my addon runs, so technically not the "same face")
[image]

My goal is to have that blue face aligned with the face the mouse goes over, which is generated from the data returned from `ray_cast`.

Thanks

Comment: It can do with a square, what should I do if the face is triangle?

Comment: @XY Good question... Not sure what the move widget does... It seems to point X,Y in the same direction regardless of tri/quad/n-gon... Do you know what X,Y is orientated to when given a face normal?

Comment: Z(Normal): cross product of 2 edges.   
X: vertex_2 - vertex_1.  
Y: Calculated from Z and X